# How to handle dispatch for Multi-Paged JSON Response in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using the following action in `React`,

```
export const fetchReminders = () => dispatch => {

    fetch(serverroute + 'reminders/', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + userCredential
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(reminders => dispatch({
            type: FETCH_REMINDERS,
            payload: reminders.results
        }));

};
```

But the API from where I'm fetching returns the results in multiple pages.
The result `JSON` looks like this,

```
{
    "count": 14,
    "next": "http://localhost:8081/reminders/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
                ......

        }
}
```

How to incorporate the multi-paged `JSON` response in my `React Action`?

Along with `React` I'm using `Redux` and `Thunk`

Answer (score 0):

You may handle this in the reducer. You can dispatch the data of each parts(from the api) and in your reducer you can push(concatinate) all the data into a single object.

And before the first api call, you may create a special dispatch to clear the data in this particular object in reducer so that the upcomming datas will be stored as a fresh sequence.

Comment: Hi I agree with your process and the knowledge which I've scoured over existing stack overflow questions these last few days explain this process but I'm stuck at the coding part.

Comment: I cant help you with that unless I have an idea how you start calling the sequence of apis and how the apis are saved. Its best if you can create a codepen or jsfiddle page with your code.

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful